# Can I play Battlefield 4 with friends who don't own DLCs'?

Tags: battlefield-4

If I get BF4 premium, can I still play with friends who don't have the DLCs/expansion packs?

I know obviously they wouldn't be able to experience the DLC content, but would I still be able to play with them? What else do I need to know about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

You and your friends will still be able to play together, however only on non-DLC maps. Make sure you check the map rotation of any server you join*. Once the server starts on a DLC map, the server will kick your friends from the game as they do not have the required content.

*To check map rotation, navigate to Server Info:

- In Server Browser press: Y [Xbox]; Triangle [PlayStation]; View Full Server Page [PC]
- In Game: Pause Menu - Server Info

Comment: I don't know how it is on console, but on PC in battlelog, there are symbols next to the server name that show which DLC are in the rotation and if there's no symbol, it's only vanilla maps. In battlelog, you can also filter out servers with DLC maps by unchecking their boxes. So if you want to play with friends without DLC, just uncheck all those boxes when searching for servers in the server browser.